# RaspberryPi date and time during boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, date, raspbian

I'm currently wondering where Raspbian gets the "current" date and time during the boot on a RaspbianPI.

The system has a RTC device connected via I2C. The date/time from the RTC is read during boot by a systemd service unit which results in the correct date/time.

Additionally the NTP client is configured.

The `fake-hwclock` package is installed but deactivated in systemd.

While Raspbian is booting it generates log messages to `/var/log/syslog` with a date/time `Nov 3 ...`. I expected it - as written by roaima - to be `Jan 1 1970` but it is not ...

Example message in `/var/log/syslog`

```
Nov  3 18:16:51 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
```

When systemd reaches the point where it runs my RTC script (the RTC device is connected via I2C) it sets the date and time correctly:

```
Oct 19 13:45:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Time has been changed
```

So, the question is: where is that strange `Nov 3` date stored?! Is it somewhere stored in a file? Is it hardcoded into the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi machines don't have a battery-backed RTC, so when they are powered up the clock starts from zero (midnight, January 1st 1970 UTC).

To get an approximation to true time at boot, before any external time source has been accessed, the `fake-hwclock` package provides a means to set the clock to a value saved at shutdown. On machines connected to the Internet, NTP can set the clock much more accurately quite quickly after the device has booted.

Comment: Well, as I've written the RaspberryPi that I use is enhanced by an RTC connected via I2C. Upon the systemd-triggered read from the RTC, the date and time are correct. fake-hwclock is disabled in systemd. Before that moment, the November 3 ... date is shown in the syslog. So this date/time must come from somewhere?

Comment: @MaxSenft I thought we were talking about the boot times recorded _before_ your RTC was read.

Comment: That's true, we're talking about the moments _before_ the RTC has been read and/or NTP is active. The fake-hwclock package is installed but not activated in systemd. The `/etc/fake-hwclock.data` file contains a different date/time. So the source for the `Nov 3 18:16:...` date/time must be something else.

Comment: I updated the question earlier. I just did another test: I created a clean Raspbian Stretch Lite SD card and booted. `fake-hwclock` is activated of course. The date/time get's set to the date `Wed 16 Aug 01:22:11 UTC 2017` by `fake-hwclock`. As soon as I disable `fake-hwclock` by `update-rc.d fake-hwclock disbale` and restart, the boot date/time is again this strange `Thu 3 Nov 17:16:51 UTC 2016`...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience where my RPi with RTC and running NTP after upgrading to Stretch sometimes doesn't use the correct date/time.

Unfortunately I can't tell you where this 3 Nov 2016 17:16:45 in Stretch comes from, but I now I think I know under which circumstances this happens.

If I compare the good and "bad date/time after reboot" situations it seems that this 3 Nov 2016 17:16:45 is not corrected to the correct time (either from the RTC or NTP) when a WLAN connection is available, the RPi is connected but for some reason cannot access the internet.

As I am very new to this Linux stuff I don't know how I can prove this.
And I am aware that I am not answering the question, but I felt this might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4 device but I've faced similar behavior (albeit predefined date differs in my case). Here are my findings:

1. As noted, `fake-hwclock` is the first obvious source of the RTC data.
2. There is initramfs hook named `fixrtc` and corresponding kernel command line parameter. If the parameter is set then early userspace hook checks last mount and creation times of the root filesystem (obtained via `dumpe2fs`). Greater time is used to set the clock.
3. If there is no `fixrtc` script and/or `fixrtc` parameter is not set. Systemd comes into play and uses it's build timestamp to set the clock. Modern Debian/Ubuntu packaging scripts extract this build timestamp from the latest `debian/changelog` entry.
4. I wasn't able to find a way to show this build timestamp using built systemd binary. However it's possible to override embedded timestamp with a custom one. The way to do that is to create/touch a file named `/usr/lib/clock-epoch`. Modification time of the file will be used as a source of the RTC data in case.